# Guacamole create a http connection

Tags: http, https, guacamole

I know Guacamole supports ssh, telnet, RDP and VNC protocols. Is there a way to create a connection directly to a webpage (http/https protocol)? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same question as I basically need a webpage to be published also.
If you have access to a docker host (might be a Pi or whatever) you could deploy something like a Firefox container and use VNC to connect to that and use the browser.